# Validation rule to compare duplicates across multiple fields in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a data entry form that inputs a title, a date, & an attendance field. Is it possible to create a validation that looks in all those fields and compares them and if it finds one where all three columns match it will disallow the entry?

I don't mind if two of the three fields match, but if they all match I'd like to stop that duplicate entry.

Possible or no?

Comment: Yes you can, by creating a multi-column unique index (see above).

Comment: That helped! Thanks. I guess I just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: No problem whatsoever. There are bad duplicates (where the asker could easily have found the question+answer), but this is definitely not one of them.